# Have we only tested our gravitational constant on our typical up and down quark matter?

Tags: particle-physics, newtonian-gravity

With gravity being so weak I know we need a fairly macroscopic amount of matter to test the value of the gravitational constant, this is hard to come by when we start looking at matter other than that which is comprised of up and down quarks. Have we been able to test gravity on other types of matter without "backing into/assuming" some of the variables?

Comment: Gravitational lensing observations test the effect of gravity on photons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matter composed of other than up and down quarks and their summed four vectors is just resonances to be found in the particle data table, heavy bosons with short lifetimes or leptons or photons.

Short lifetimes  do not allow the possibility of experimentation as no beam or bulk matter can be produced.

This is a talk on [Gravitational Measurements on Charged Particles](https://indico.cern.ch/event/361413/contributions/1776296/attachments/1137816/1628821/WAG2015.pdf) that may interest you as it talks of a $g_{eff}$ for electrons .

Also refers to  *F.C. Witteborn, William M. Fairbank; Nature 220 (1968) 436Experiments to determine the Force of Gravity on Single Electrons and Positron*

[There are studies r](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269315006723)elated to electron beams at the level of general relativity, which would show differences in the gravitational constant  when approximated to Newtonian gravity.

Comment: Photons and neutrinos are stable ... but they're hard to keep in one place for long enough and in sufficient quantities.